# Is there any way to avoiding typing this same code continuously in Android(Kotlin)

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, imageview, dry

I am looking for advice on if its possible to use the same parameters here instead of copying and pasting the same code over and over again.

I am trying to move blocks around on an App for visual affects. There are a bunch of blocks(imageViews) on the screen and I want most of them to make the same motions, however, i know DRY (Don't repeat yourself) is taught often and i see this as literally doing that. Is there any way to do this without continuously repeating myself?

```
        var mScanner = (imageView1)
        var mAnimation = TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f
        )
        mAnimation.setDuration(2500)
        mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1)
        mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE)
        mAnimation.setInterpolator(LinearInterpolator())
        mScanner.setAnimation(mAnimation)

        var mScanner2 = (imageView2)
        var mAnimation2 = TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f
        )
        mAnimation2.setDuration(2500)
        mAnimation2.setRepeatCount(-1)
        mAnimation2.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE)
        mAnimation2.setInterpolator(LinearInterpolator())
        mScanner2.setAnimation(mAnimation2)
```

I am hoping to be capable of using the same block of code without 
having to copy and paste it continuously for multiple imageViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a helper function for reducing the redundant code, also you can use kotlin's scope function to make your code clean.

```
/**
 * Helper function for setting animation to a image view
 */
private fun setupAnimation(imageView: ImageView) {

        val animation = TranslateAnimation(
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f
        )

        animation.apply {
            duration = 2500
            repeatCount = -1
            repeatMode = Animation.REVERSE
            interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        }
        imageView.animation = animation
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a helper function with dynamic parameters like this

```
private fun setupAnimation(scanner: Scanner, imageView: Imageview) {
    scanner = (imageView)
    val animation = TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f
    )
    animation.setDuration(2500)
    animation.setRepeatCount(-1)
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE)
    animation.setInterpolator(LinearInterpolator())
    scanner.setAnimation(animation)
}
```

and you can call this function multiple times